# Reference .net core 2.0 into a .net 45/46 project

Tags: entity-framework-core, visual-studio-mac, .net-core-2.0

How can I add a reference of a .Net Core 2.0 project into my .Net 46 project?

My project is structured as follow:

Solution
- Data Project (.Net Core 2.0)
- Test Project (.Net 46)

I'm trying to reference the Data Project into my Test Project as I need to insert some data using it. The only reason I created a .Net Core 2.0 is that I'm trying to use Entity Framework on Visual Studio for Mac and it didn't work using the "normal" Entity Framework nuget package, so I opted for the EntityFrameworkCore.

I was able to manually reference the Data Project dll, but then when I run a test I get the message

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.0.0. Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies"
```

Is there any solution for this? If not, what's the best way to work with Visual Studio on Mac and Sql Server when you need to retrieve and insert data? Would Dapper work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you asked is impossible.

.NET Framework projects can only consume .NET Standard Class Library projects, but not .NET Core projects.

See the reference for more information,

https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff